# Model null on POST

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I'm working on a project developed by some people that i don't actually knows. I encountered a problem on a POST method. The model is actually null. It looks like that the model is not populated on the view.

```cs
public ActionResult ConfermaRistampa(int IDTitolo, Ristampa ristampa) //Ristampa is the model
{
    //some code
    if (ristampa.RichiestaRistampaWeb != null) //the field "RichiestaRistampaWeb" is null
    {
        ristampa.RichiestaRistampa = Utilities.ConverteFileInToFileUploadInfo(ristampa.RichiestaRistampaWeb, TipiDocumenti.Documento_Generico);
    }
}

//this is the code of field on the Ristampa class declaration, in the set i noticed that value is null
public System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase RichiestaRistampaWeb
{
    get
    {
        return this.RichiestaRistampaWebField;
    }
    set
    {
        if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.RichiestaRistampaWebField, value) != true))
        {
            this.RichiestaRistampaWebField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("RichiestaRistampaWeb");
        }
    }
}
```

That's the entire model definition. It's ASP.NET Core using MVC obviously. I noticed that most attributes of the model are nulls on the setters.

```cs
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name = "Ristampa", Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RSM.SourceData.Models.Serialized")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public partial class Ristampa : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    [System.NonSerializedAttribute()]
    private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private string ComuneLicenzaField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private string DenominazioneField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private decimal ImportoOperazioneField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private RSM.BusTuristiciWeb.SourceDataReference.FileUploadInfo LibrettoDiCircolazioneField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase LibrettoDiCircolazioneWebField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private RSM.BusTuristiciWeb.SourceDataReference.FileUploadInfo LicenzaField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase LicenzaWebField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private string MotivazioneField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private string NumeroLicenzaField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private RSM.BusTuristiciWeb.SourceDataReference.FileUploadInfo RicevutaPagamentoField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase RicevutaPagamentoWebField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private RSM.BusTuristiciWeb.SourceDataReference.FileUploadInfo RichiestaRistampaField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase RichiestaRistampaWebField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> ScadenzaLicenzaField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private string TargaAttualeField;

    [global::System.ComponentModel.BrowsableAttribute(false)]
    public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
    {
        get
        {
            return this.extensionDataField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.extensionDataField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string ComuneLicenza
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ComuneLicenzaField;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.ComuneLicenzaField, value) != true))
            {
                this.ComuneLicenzaField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("ComuneLicenza");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string Denominazione
    {
        get
        {
            return this.DenominazioneField;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.DenominazioneField, value) != true))
            {
                this.DenominazioneField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Denominazione");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public decimal ImportoOperazione
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ImportoOperazioneField;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this.ImportoOperazioneField.Equals(value) != true))
            {
                this.ImportoOperazioneField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("ImportoOperazione");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public RSM.BusTuristiciWeb.SourceDataReference.FileUploadInfo LibrettoDiCircolazione
    {
        get
        {
            return this.LibrettoDiCircolazioneField;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.LibrettoDiCircolazioneField, value) != true))
            {
                this.LibrettoDiCircolazioneField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("LibrettoDiCircolazione");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase LibrettoDiCircolazioneWeb
    {
        get
        {
            return this.LibrettoDiCircolazioneWebField;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.LibrettoDiCircolazioneWebField, value) != true))
            {
                this.LibrettoDiCircolazioneWebField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("LibrettoDiCircolazioneWeb");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public RSM.BusTuristiciWeb.SourceDataReference.FileUploadInfo Licenza
    {
        get
        {
            return this.LicenzaField;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.LicenzaField, value) != true))
            {
                this.LicenzaField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Licenza");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase LicenzaWeb
    {
        get
        {
            return this.LicenzaWebField;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.LicenzaWebField, value) != true))
            {
                this.LicenzaWebField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("LicenzaWeb");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string Motivazione
    {
        get
        {
            return this.MotivazioneField;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.MotivazioneField, value) != true))
            {
                this.MotivazioneField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Motivazione");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string NumeroLicenza
    {
        get
        {
            return this.NumeroLicenzaField;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.NumeroLicenzaField, value) != true))
            {
                this.NumeroLicenzaField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("NumeroLicenza");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public RSM.BusTuristiciWeb.SourceDataReference.FileUploadInfo RicevutaPagamento
    {
        get
        {
            return this.RicevutaPagamentoField;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.RicevutaPagamentoField, value) != true))
            {
                this.RicevutaPagamentoField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("RicevutaPagamento");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase RicevutaPagamentoWeb
    {
        get
        {
            return this.RicevutaPagamentoWebField;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.RicevutaPagamentoWebField, value) != true))
            {
                this.RicevutaPagamentoWebField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("RicevutaPagamentoWeb");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public RSM.BusTuristiciWeb.SourceDataReference.FileUploadInfo RichiestaRistampa
    {
        get
        {
            return this.RichiestaRistampaField;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.RichiestaRistampaField, value) != true))
            {
                this.RichiestaRistampaField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("RichiestaRistampa");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase RichiestaRistampaWeb
    {
        get
        {
            return this.RichiestaRistampaWebField;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.RichiestaRistampaWebField, value) != true))
            {
                this.RichiestaRistampaWebField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("RichiestaRistampaWeb");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public System.Nullable<System.DateTime> ScadenzaLicenza
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ScadenzaLicenzaField;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this.ScadenzaLicenzaField.Equals(value) != true))
            {
                this.ScadenzaLicenzaField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("ScadenzaLicenza");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string TargaAttuale
    {
        get
        {
            return this.TargaAttualeField;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.TargaAttualeField, value) != true))
            {
                this.TargaAttualeField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("TargaAttuale");
            }
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null))
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

That's the form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ConfermaRistampa", "Abbonamenti", new { @IDTitolo = Request.QueryString["IDTitolo"] }, FormMethod.Post, null))
{
    <br />
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr class="color">
                <th>
                    @Html.Label(Risorse.Language.TargaAttuale)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.Label(Risorse.Language.Motivazione)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.Label(Risorse.Language.Importo)
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TargaAttuale)

                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Motivazione, new SelectList(motivazioni, "Key", "Value"), "[Scegli una motivazione]", new { id = "ddlMotivazione", onchange = "SetPanelMotivazione();", required = "required" })

                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ImportoOperazione)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>




    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.Label(Risorse.Language.DichiarazioneRichiestaRistampa + ":")
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RichiestaRistampaWeb, new { type = "file", required = "required" })
        </div>
        @*<div class="col-sm-6">
                @Html.Label(Risorse.Language.LibrettoDiCircolazione + ":")
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LibrettoDiCircolazioneWeb, new { type = "file", required = "required" })
            </div>*@
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="pnlLicense" style="display:none">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                @Html.Label(Risorse.Language.NumeroLicenza)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NumeroLicenza)
                @Html.ValidationMessage("errNumLicenza", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                @Html.Label(Risorse.Language.Provincia)
                @Html.DropDownList("ddlProvince", new SelectList(listaProvince, "Key", "Value"), "Seleziona la provincia", new { @id = "ddlProvince", @onchange = "javascript:GetComuni(this.value, '#ddlComuni');" })
                @Html.ValidationMessage("errProvince", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                @Html.Label(Risorse.Language.Comune)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ComuneLicenza, new SelectList(new List<string>()), new { id = "ddlComuni" })
                @Html.ValidationMessage("errComune", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                @Html.Label(Risorse.Language.ScadenzaLicenza)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ScadenzaLicenza, new { type = "text", @language = "it", @class = "datepicker-here" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                @Html.Label(Risorse.Language.DocumentazioneNuovaLicenza + ":")
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LicenzaWeb, new { type = "file" })
            </div>
            @*<div class="col-sm-6">
                    @Html.Label(Risorse.Language.RicevutaAvvenutaPagamento + ":")
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RicevutaPagamentoWeb, new { type = "file" })
                </div>*@
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="pnlRagSoc" style="display:none">
        <h4 class="colorH4">
            @Html.Label(Risorse.Language.DatiNuovoIntestatario)
        </h4>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                @Html.Label(Risorse.Language.Denominazione)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Denominazione)
                @Html.ValidationMessage("errDenominazione", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="submit" value="@Risorse.Language.Invia" class="btnRegister btn btn-default" />
            <input type="button" value="@Risorse.Language.Annulla" onclick="Annulla();" class="btnRegister btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Is this ASP.Net Core or plain ASP.Net? Can you post your model and the json? Are you using attribute routing?

Comment: I modified the post

Comment: In your html form, is the 'enctype' set to "multipart/form-data"? And the 'name' attribute of your file input field is 'RichiestaRistampa'?

Comment: Sorry, it's not plai ASP.NET but ASP.NET core, with cshtml files.

Comment: Post the form in the question, including the 'form' part.

Comment: i added the part of the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you cshtml form, set the enctype to 'multipart/form-data'. Otherwise files will not be included in your model:

```
// Magic all the way to the right -->
@using (Html.BeginForm("ConfermaRistampa", "Abbonamenti", new { @IDTitolo = Request.QueryString["IDTitolo"] }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data" }))
```